# Error when deploying Azure ML model to modelmanagement

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

When executing the command below:

`az ml model register -m <pkl name>.pkl -n <model name> -d "dummy model" --debug --verbose`

I get the error stating that the URL cannot be connected to. The verbose message does not show any error before the one below. I can confirm that the model management account and environments have been set.

I am using the Visual Studio subscription to test out some functionality. Any help is appreciated!

```
{
    "Azure-cli-ml Version": "0.1.0a27.post3",
    "Error": "Error connecting to https://australiaeast.modelmanagement.azureml.net/api/subscriptions/ad19a4a2-ed65-4574-aec3-e247c4d96efd/resourceGroups/rcity-rg-bi-001-azureml-3797f/accounts/rcity-bi-mlexpmgmt-002/models."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the Azure Machine Learning team. We'd like to help -- it doesnt look like the command you entered is complete. If you'd like us to help you troubleshoot it, you can email us at amlfb@microsoft.com.

- Serina